# Is there a pattern for executing multiple throwing functions after each other?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm looking for a nice way to write code with exceptions if I want to ignore them in a piece of code.

Consider

```
bool ClearAllCaches() {
    bool success = ClearPersistentCache();
    success &= ClearTransientCache();
    success &= ClearRemoteCache();
    return success;
}
```

If these functions were throwing instead of returning a success value, and I also want to re-throw any exception that one of these throws, but only after all are done, is there a cleaner solution than this?

```
void ClearAllCaches() {
    MyException persistentException = MyException(ErrorCode::None);
    try {
        ClearPersistentCache();
    } catch (const MyException& e) {
        persistentException = e;
    }
    //...same for ClearTransientCache()
    ClearRemoteCache(); // <- does not have to be caught.
    if (persistentException.getCode() != ErrorCode::None) {
        throw persistentException;
    }
    //...same for ClearTransientCache()
}
```

Is it possible to write this in a readable and not overly ugly manner?

Comment: If an exception has occurred, it is necessary to fix the cause.  Catching the exception, continuing on as if it hadn't happened, and then rethrowing is completely at odds with that.    And what would you expect to do if two of the functions throw?

Comment: An exception should indicate something exceptional that needs to be fixed. You should not use exceptions for controlling program flow, this is considered bad programming style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda and `std::exception_ptr`:

```
void ClearAllCaches() {
    std::exception_ptr eptr;
    auto CallAndStoreException = [&](auto func) {
        try {
            func();
        } catch (...) {
            eptr = std::current_exception();
        }
    };

    CallAndStoreException(&ClearPersistentCache);
    CallAndStoreException(&ClearTransientCache);
    CallAndStoreException(&ClearRemoteCache);

    if (eptr) {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
}
```

But are you sure exceptions are the right way if you throw away the information of those thrown first? If you are sure you have to go this way, maybe also have a look at [`std::nested_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception)

Comment: Possibly worth pointing out the major difference between using `std::exception_ptr` and copying the `MyException`: if anyone ever defines a class that derives from `MyException` and throws that, `exception_ptr` will preserve that derived information, but the copy method will slice it off.